# Access files stored in [NSFileManager containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier] for debugging

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsfilemanager, ios8-extension

I have an app with the following code:

```
NSURL *containerURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.myCo.myApp"];
[containerURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Myfile"]];
```

Reading and writing from `Myfile` is working, but I'd like to be able to access the file directly on my phone for debugging and testing purposes.

It's not in App's container (Window > Devices >> Download container), is it really not accessible to developers who have the device attached to the computer? I feel like I'm missing something here?

Comment: If you got the solution then ..please upload your code...Because i have same problem.

Comment: Currently I have no solution. Luckily it has not gotten urgent yet.. If you find something please update here too!